# Zend and Jquery, how to write in zend

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, jquery-plugins

In header.php file , below is used

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/library/includes/jQuery142.js">
</script> // jquery
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/library/includes/jqueryautoiframe.js">
</script>    // plugin iFrame Sizing
```

in view file below code, How do i put below in to zend ?I used below code but not working.

```
<iframe src="blabla"></iframe>
<script>
$('iframe').iframeAutoHeight(); //iframeAutoHeight is the function in jqueryautoiframe.js
</script>
```

Comment: are you gettinng errors in firebug

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait until the document is ready before you can use any js

try this:

```
<script>
$(function() { 
     $('iframe').iframeAutoHeight(); //iframeAutoHeight is the function in jqueryautoiframe.js
});
</script>
```

Comment: I guess since iframe tag was above script hence no need of putting it inside ready handler .

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('iframe').iframeAutoHeight(); //iframeAutoHeight is the function in jqueryautoiframe.js
</script>
```

Your iframe source is 'blabla' did you put it intentionally ??

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<?php
$this->headScript()
->appendScript(
    <<<'BODY'
    $('iframe').iframeAutoHeight();
    });
BODY
);
?>
```